# Authentication pop up on a desktop app: what if it is much bigger than main app window?

Tags: popup, authentication, desktop, google

I am working on a desktop app that requires authentication. It allows federated authentication using different services, Google among them. Most probably, we'll use a pop up with a browser window to allow the user to authenticate.

Showing a small modal popup centered on the main app window seems like an elegant solution. However, the Google login page is rather big, certainly bigger than our own window. I see two options, but I don't like neither:

- Making the app window bigger to allow showing the pop up inside it. Is this a good idea?
- Just show a pop up in a different window, hiding the main window behind it. This is even worse for me, as it would enforce this design for the other providers for the sake of consistency.

Any other options?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Google's OAuth system correctly? Most of the times a small simple form shows.

Comment: I'm using Azure ACS. This is the page shown: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=es&continue=http://www.google.es/

Comment: yes, I just checked with the oauth authentication here in stackexchange and the same thing happens. What they do is redirect to the google login page and then back.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an initial smaller popup window with scrollbars **and** an option to expand it to full screen by clicking an icon. I am not sure if this is consistent with design practice, but might suit your needs without overly inconveniencing either the user or the other providers.

Comment: Yes, but the login controls on the google page are on the right side, making the window expansion mandatory. That would add one more click necessary. THanks!

Comment: Location of login controls may not be a constraint. As the page loads, control is given to the first input box bringing it into view in the window - however small it may be. I suppose this is what you had meant.

Comment: Well, we can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for some 'Connection wizard' that pops-up over the main application or even replacing the main application. The user can then use the wizard to log into whatever services they want. When they're done you'll simply close the 'Connection wizard' and reshow you're application.